# simple set up for elderly relative?

Tags: skype

I have a 95 year old relative who really appreciates being able to Skype.
But she is a bit phobic to technology. She had a Windows laptop, but it eventually wouldn't update Skype properly, and I was wondering whether a simple Ubuntu set up would be better.

It would need to install updates  automatically. And also log in to Skype easily (no password usernames to remember))  it feels like his really ought to be possible. I can do simple set ups and a bit of command line, though am bit of a newbie myself